# Replace Due Date with Completed Date/Time field at Activity History

Tags: lightning, sales-cloud, activityhistory, force

Is it possible to add Completed Date/Time to Activity History on the layout instead of Due Date? Normally, the Due Date is displayed on the Activity History Page, with the order descending from the Due Date field. We want to display the Completed Date/Time field on the activity history layout, and the records must be ordered descendingly based on the Completed Date/Time field. Could someone please help me.

Please find the below Activity History sample UI screenshot.

[image: Activity History UI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tasks_customize_fields.htm&type=5), Certain fields remain in the task list even if you remove them from a layout, because they contain essential task information, including the **subject, status, and due date fields**. For example, suppose that you remove the status and due date fields from a compact layout. The task checkbox and the due date still appear on tasks in the list. The remaining fields visible in the list reflect the fields you include in the compact layout.

- From Setup, at the top of the page, select Object Manager
- Click Task.
- Click Compact Layouts.
- Click New. If you’ve already created a custom compact layout for
  tasks, select it.
- If you’re creating a new compact layout, enter a name and label for
  it.
- Select the task fields you want to display on the activity timeline.
- Click Save.
- Click Compact Layout Assignment.
- Click Edit Assignment.
- Select the new or updated layout.
- Click Save.

When you click Expand All on the activity timeline, you see the selected task fields.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this setting.

1. From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Activity, and then select
   Activity Settings.
2. To sort past activities by the completed date, select Sort past activities by the completed date. To sort past  activities by the due date, deselect Sort past activities by the completed date.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activitytimeline_sorting_past_activities_task.htm&type=5

Comment: This solution nails it. Used in combo with the first, it's a powerful change to the system.